# PHP Compare DateTimeZone Objects

Tags: php, unit-testing, datetime, timezone

Is this the only way to compare a DateTimeZone Object to a given Timezone?

```
    $dateNow = new \DateTime('now');
    $tz = $dateNow->getTimezone();
    $this->assertEquals($tz->getName(), $tz->listIdentifiers(\DateTimeZone::UTC)[0]);
```

Neither comparing two objects nor comparing the constants works. By the way, what are the DateTimeZone constants used for?

Comment: Please watch your grammar. A question with poor grammar is less likely to get answers. I fixed that for you for now.

Answer (score 0):

Two DateTimeZone objects can be compared by their respective names.

An example using only DateTimeZone objects:

```
$UTC = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$UTC2 = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$PST = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
if ($UTC->getName() == $PST->getName())
{
    echo "UTC equals PST";
}
else
{
    echo "UTC does not equal PST";
}

if ($UTC->getName() == $UTC2->getName())
{
    echo "UTC equals UTC";
}
else
{
    echo "UTC does not equal UTC";
}
```

An example using DateTime objects:

```
$now_UTC = new DateTime('now');
$now_UTC->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$now_PST = new DateTime('now');
$now_PST->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));

if ($now_UTC->getTimezone()->getName() == $now_PST->getTimezone()->getName())
{
    echo "UTC equals PST";
}
else
{
    echo "UTC does not equal PST";
}

$now_PST->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

if ($now_UTC->getTimezone()->getName() == $now_PST->getTimezone()->getName())
{
    echo "UTC equals UTC";
}
else
{
    echo "UTC does not equal UTC";
}
```